# VS Code launch with default user profile not working

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my angular application, and I need to access my default user profile's cookies. When I state `"userDataDir": false` VS code throws an error,

[image]

Below is my launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:4301",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "userDataDir": false
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to Chrome",
        "port": 9222,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you check if the firewall is blocking the port or the port is already occupied?

Comment: I checked, the port is working. I can serve the application on that port but debug. And also if I remove `"userDataDir": false` from the json it works fine.